# retry ansible failed task using callback plugin

Tags: python, error-handling, ansible, ansible-tower

Here is my question. 
I would like to retry a task runned from ansible-tower which failed using a custom callback plugin, however I don't even know if it is possible to perform this action using callback.

For now I'm able to print details about the job when it's failing... and that's all.

Here is my function which is handling the errors on each run.

```
def v2_runner_on_failed(self, result, ignore_errors=False):
    payload = {'state': 'failed',
                   'task_name': result.task_name,
                   'task_output' : result._result['msg']
                  }

    print(payload)
```

Having those information is fine but this is not what I excactly need.

Am I looking for something "impossible" ?

Regards,
Remy

Comment: What is actually wrong with the classic retry in ansible ? https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met

Comment: @Zeitounator I would like this process to be the most "generic" possible. I don't want to edit all of my playbooks. This is why I'm trying to perform this using a plugin.

Comment: Sorry but what you are saying is going exactly against what you are actually doing. The most generic way is to use the classic retry functionality build in ansible + you do not want to retry all your tasks (do you?). If you count on that for your playbook to work, then it will fail when the plugin is not present (not generic....). I can understand you want to do that, but that is certainly not generic.

Comment: @Zeitounator What we (my team and I) are trying to do is to retry each time we have a failed task. Might sound weird but what we are trying to implement is a brand new process with auto generated tickets and all. Atm, we have like more than hundreds playbooks which are already used in production. Going back in dev and edit all the yml files is not something we can afford right now.

Comment: So basically, you are trying to change the overall behavior of ansible and it is not generic as I suspected. My first feeling is that you are playing with a match box in the middle of a very dry forest. But maybe I'm just too old and conservative. Meanwhile, the only good advice I can give you here is to triple check you are not hitting an X/Y problem here and that your base problem is really to retry any ansible task in any playbook. Good luck.